# Cannot allow element (img: 'src') with symfony html-sanitizer (symfony6.3 php 8.2)

Tags: php, html, symfony6

As per `https://symfony.com/doc/current/html_sanitizer.html#allow-elements` I created an html sanitizer implementation:

- config/packages/html_sanitizer.yaml

```yaml
framework:
    html_sanitizer:
        sanitizers:
            app.post_sanitizer:
                allow_safe_elements: true
                #allow_static_elements: true
                allow_elements:
                    img: '*'
                    #img: ['src', 'class']
                    span: '*'
                    p: 'class'
```

- Controller/TestController.php

```php
#[Route('/read_html', name: 'read_html')]
public function readHtml(HtmlSanitizerInterface $appPostSanitizer): Response {
$testHtml = '<div>
    <span style="font-size: 21pt;">This some big text</span>
    <img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600" class="img-fluid" >
    <p class="text-danger">this is some red text in bootstrap!</p>
</div>';
$testHtml2 = $appPostSanitizer->sanitize($testHtml);
dd($testHtml, $testHtml2);
    }
```

- output:

```html
"""
<div>
    <span style="font-size: 21pt;">This some big text</span>
    <img alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600" class="img-fluid" />
    <p class="text-danger">this is some red text in bootstrap!</p>
</div>
"""
```

i.e. everything else works except `src` in `img` tag.

`src="img_girl.jpg"` is missing.

I have tried any combination I could think of like :`img: ['src', 'class']` `img: 'src'`.
Still could not make src show up after sanitization.

Comment: maybe you also need `allow_relative_medias: true` ?

Comment: @Dirk J. Fabe : just checked it and it worked ! Thank you. Maybe add it as an answer so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set `allow_relative_medias: true`.

When you set `allow_relative_medias` to `true`, you instruct the sanitizer to make an exception for relative URLs. Relative URLs are URLs that do not include the full web address and protocol (e.g., `img_girl.jpg`).

Read more in the docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/html_sanitizer.html#force-allow-media-urls